# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to integrate the Redux into the reactjs.I found the following error message in the dev tool.May i know what is this exactly and how can we solve it?

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.
    at dispatch (createStore.js:158)
    at eval (middleware.js:22)
    at eval (middleware.js:67)
    at Object.eval [as callApi] (bindActionCreators.js:5)
    at HomePage.componentDidMount (eval at ./app/containers/HomePage/index.js (0.chunk.js:154), <anonymous>:101:28)
    at HomePage.proxiedComponentDidMount (eval at ./node_modules/react-proxy/modules/createPrototypeProxy.js (0.chunk.js:943), <anonymous>:61:40)
    at eval (ReactCompositeComponent.js:265)
    at measureLifeCyclePerf (ReactCompositeComponent.js:75)
    at eval (ReactCompositeComponent.js:264)
    at CallbackQueue.notifyAll (CallbackQueue.js:76)
```

Comment: I see a file a file in you code: ```bindActionCreators.js```, so you want to use action creators. Have you installed ```redux-thunk``` properly? https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk#installation

Answer (score 0):

I think you are passing a function in the dispatch function, which is not supported by default. If you want to do such a thing, you should use thunk middleware.

```
import {createStore, compose, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';

function configureStoreProd(initialState) {
  const middlewares = [
    // Add other middleware on this line...

    // thunk middleware can also accept an extra argument to be passed to each thunk action
    // https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk#injecting-a-custom-argument
    thunk,
  ];

  return createStore(rootReducer, initialState, compose(
      applyMiddleware(...middlewares)
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: where will i add these code or i need to add it in the store.js file?